# How can one know which way mining pools will vote for P2SH?

Tags: p2sh

Is there a list somewhere showing how each mining pool will vote on the P2SH question?

and

If a pool says that it is voting one way, is it possible to independently verify that they are indeed voting that way with their mining power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out this page:

http://blockchain.info/p2sh

If you want to verify if a given pool operator has indeed mined the blocks for the votes, he or she can sign some message with the private keys corresponding to the public addresses that were the recipients of the block reward.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your pool operator.  Luke-Jr, the operator of Eligius, has been quite transparent about [his objection to P2SH](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=58579.0) and decision to record a "no" vote in blocks mined by his pool.

Comment: Eligius supports P2SH, just not BIP 16 which is broken by design. We are voting BIP 17, which solves the problem in a manner consistent with the current Bitcoin system.