# How is the extra nonce formatted?

Tags: block, hash, coinbase-transaction, nonce

I'm trying to understand how a block is put together. From [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36455/determining-a-blocks-extranonce-value), I know that the extra nonce used to be in the format:

```
pblock->vtx[0].vin[0].scriptSig = CScript() << pblock->nTime << CBigNum(nExtraNonce);
```

What does this syntax mean? Exactly what elements does the script sig contain and in what order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this syntax mean?

It's C++ for "set the scriptSig of the first input in the first transaction in this block to have the same contents as a script with the encoded nTime followed by the encoded nExtraNone".

> Exactly what elements does the script sig contain and in what order?

It contains the block's `nTime`, followed by by the `nExtraNonce`.

> How is the extra nonce formatted?

An example from this time period would be in the scriptSig from [the coinbase transaction of block #185000](https://blockchain.info/tx/30d6f63aca6cef1ed958c35b83ca35e042ccff36e75d9c195534f0f6a7a8d31a):

```
04d508de4f02e82d
```

If we parse this script sig, it is:

```
04 -- Number of bytes in group of data
  d508de4f -- 4 bytes. The little endian timestamp.
02 -- Number of bytes in group of data
  e82d --  the little endian extranonce
```

Notice when you reverse the bytes in `d508de4f`, you get `4fde08d5`, which when you convert it to a timestamp is `Sun Jun 17 2012 12:41:57 GMT-0400 (EDT)`. When you byte-reverse `e82d` (reversed is `2de8`), and decode an integer from the hex, you get 11,752 for an extranonce value.

Comment: Has this always been the way the first transaction scriptSig is formatted?

Comment: As you can see in [the question you linked to](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/36455/determining-a-blocks-extranonce-value), no, it has not always been this way. In addition, there are only a few requirements about how the miner has to format their coinbase's scriptSigs, they can add any extra data they want to.